Can scipy.optimize Find Optimal Input Values When Multiple Products are Involved?
I'd like to find the optimal values for Input A for Product 1 and for Input A for Product 2 with the aim to maximize  Total Output and subject to a given constraint. I've tried using Python's Scipy minimize function and it works if I have just one Product but it does not work for multiple Products.
Can scipy.optimize Find Optimal Input Values When Multiple Products are Involved?
Here is what I tried assuming just two Products exist (In reality I have several thousand such Products):
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

Product1_InputB = np.array([0.5])
Product1_InputC = np.array([1])
Product1_InputD = np.array([1])
Product1_InputE = np.array([0.08])
Product1_InputF = np.array([20])

Product2_InputB = np.array([0.5])
Product2_InputC = np.array([1])
Product2_InputD = np.array([2])
Product2_InputE = np.array([0.1])
Product2_InputF = np.array([30])

def Neg_Product1_Output(Product1_InputA):
    return -1 * ((2.71828**((Product1_InputA-Product1_InputB)*(0.5*Product1_InputC-1.5*Product1_InputD)))/(1+(2.71828**((Product1_InputA-Product1_InputB)*(0.5*Product1_InputC-1.5*Product1_InputD))))*(Product1_InputA-Product1_InputB))

def Neg_Product2_Output(Product2_InputA):
    return -1 * ((2.71828**((Product2_InputA-Product2_InputB)*(0.5*Product2_InputC-1.5*Product2_InputD)))/(1+(2.71828**((Product2_InputA-Product2_InputB)*(0.5*Product2_InputC-1.5*Product2_InputD))))*(Product2_InputA-Product2_InputB))

def Neg_Total_Output(Product1_InputA,Product2_InputA):
    return Neg_Product1_Output + Neg_Product2_Output

def constraint(Product1_InputA, Product2_InputA):
    return (((Product1_InputA - Product1_InputE) * Neg_Product1_Output) + ((Product2_InputA - Product2_InputE) * Neg_Product2_Output)) / Neg_Total_Output - 2

con = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': constraint}

Product1_InputA_Initial_Guess = np.array([3])
Product1_InputA_Initial_Guess = np.asarray([3])
Product2_InputA_Initial_Guess = np.array([1])
Product2_InputA_Initial_Guess = np.asarray([1])
Product1_bound = [(0.3,4)]
Product2_bound = [(0.3,4)]

optimized_results = minimize(Neg_Total_Output,Product1_InputA_Initial_Guess,bounds=Product1_bound,constraints=con)

Product1_InputA_Optimal = optimized_results.x
Product1_InputA_Optimal

When I run the line optimized_results = ... I get the below error:
TypeError: constraint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Product2_InputA'

Am not sure how to include Product2 in the optimized_results minimize function above.

the syntax on this line is oncorrect Product1_InputB = np.array(\[0.5\])

what arethe purposes of all the backslashes "" in the code ? they all look like sytnax errors.

in Neg_Total_Output you are adding two functions together (which makes no sense). I suppose you want to add results of those functions

This does not seem feasible. You have a Product1_bound - what is your product 2 bound?

@D.L Stack Overflow adds backslashes before [ and ] if you paste those characters into the editor without a code block

I edited the code so that it appears in code block format and that fixed the backslashes. Also, added the Product_bound and updated the initial guess so that it satisfies the constraint. Thank you

You've modified your initial guess to 0.3 but that still makes no sense; it doesn't satisfy your constraint.

You have stability and convergence issues, but at least to address the "multiple products" question this is very straightforward:
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint, Bounds


def neg_product_output(
    a: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray,
    c: np.ndarray,
    d: np.ndarray,
    e: np.ndarray,
    f: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    inner = np.exp(
        (a - b)*(0.5*c - 1.5*d)
    )
    return -inner/(1 + inner)*(a - b)


def neg_total_output(
    a: np.ndarray,
    bcdef: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    out = neg_product_output(a, *bcdef)
    return out.sum()


def constraint(
    a: np.ndarray,
    bcdef: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    out = neg_product_output(a, *bcdef)
    b, c, d, e, f = bcdef
    return (a - e).dot(out) / out.sum()


def solve(
    bcdef: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # con - 2 >= 0: con >= 2
    con = NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=partial(constraint, bcdef=bcdef),
        lb=2,
        # The solver does not support an infinite upper bound to this constraint
        ub=100,
    )

    a12_guess = np.full(shape=bcdef.shape[1], fill_value=3.)
    lb = np.full_like(a12_guess, fill_value=0.3)
    ub = np.full_like(a12_guess, fill_value=2.25)
    f = bcdef[-1, :]
    ub[f == 30] = 2.5
    ub[f >= 40] = 3.0

    results = minimize(
        fun=neg_total_output, args=(bcdef,),
        x0=a12_guess, bounds=Bounds(lb=lb, ub=ub),
        constraints=con, tol=1e-12,
    )
    if not results.success:
        raise ValueError(results.message)
    print(results.message, 'in', results.nit, 'iterations')
    return results.x


def main() -> None:
    a = solve(
        bcdef=np.array((
            ( 0.5 ,  0.5 ),
            ( 1.  ,  1.  ),
            ( 1.  ,  2.  ),
            ( 0.08,  0.1 ),
            (20.  , 30.  ),
        )),
    )
    print('a =')
    print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Optimization terminated successfully in 12 iterations
a =
[2.25       1.51094911]


Thank you Reinderien! The code you provided works! Have two follow-up questions. 1. How can I modify the bounds for the following conditions (they apply to both products)? If Product1_InputF = 20 then Product1_bound = [(0.3,2.25)] , If Product1_InputF = 30 then Product1_bound = [(0.3,2.5)], If Product1_InputF = 40 then Product1_bound = [(0.3,3)] and how can I run this code if I have several thousand products (The input data is in Excel)?

how can I run this code if I have several thousand products (The input data is in Excel) - you can't. It would require rework, and you haven't shown a reproducible example for arbitrary input size; you'd need to file a new question.

Regarding input F bounds, write a lookup table in the form of a dictionary in the problem setup that sets individual bounds for A1 and A2 based on the value of F1 and F2.

Okay, will file a new question providing sample data that covers beyond just the two products shared here. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it!

@Coder_Needing_Help I've added my best guess here with only the two products, where the inner solution routine is vectorised and can be extended to multiple products. If this answers your question for the case of two products, consider marking it as accepted.

@Reinderien I accepted the solution. It is a very elegant solution! Thank you!  Now I just need to figure out how to bring in the large dataset with all the products from Excel into the  bcdef=np.array function at the end of the code but that should be doable.
